# How to use shared library in ASP.Net Core MVC running on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm looking into using ASP.Net Core MVC for some of my new projects.  I work on a team of developers for a very large organization, and we each individually write a lot of small web apps.  Due to the size of our organization, we have a lot of rules that we have to follow, and sometimes those rules change, completely out of our control.  So this is what we have used in the past projects, all running on IIS:

- ASP Classic - Each IIS root folder has a shared folder, containing a lot of commonly used .asp files.  These files are mostly the same on each server, but can point to different databases for dev/test/prod environments.  These library files are used for common things like authentication, authorization, encryption, sending emails, etc...  Each application would be in a sibling folder to the shared folder, and include files like "..\shared\library.asp"
- ASP.Net / MVC - The closest thing we could find was the GAC.  Everybody says not to use the GAC, but for our purposes it does exactly what we need.  We built a DLL library, and store it in the GAC of each web server.  We then put local configuration (dev/test/prod environment specific stuff) information on the global web.config of each IIS server.  Application specific information would be stored in that application's local web.config file.

The beauty of these two systems, is sometimes things change, and we can simply go update the global libraries, and every application that depends on them will adapt to the new code without needing a recompile.  We have many applications, running on many web servers.  This may not be ideal, but for our needs it works perfectly, considering the rules can change at a moment's notice, and recompiling every application would be a huge ordeal.  We just have to be sure not to ever introduce breaking changes into our libraries, which is simple enough.  We have zero problems with how it works.

Now, on to ASP.Net Core.  Is there an elegant way to do this?  It seems like Core doesn't support the GAC, nor does it support web.config.  Everything wants to use appsettings.json.  Is there a way to create an appsettings.json at the root level of IIS, and have it set global variables like environment="dev", authdatabase="devsql" etc?  And can we store a .Net Core/Standard DLL in a shared folder, and have every app load it with a path like "..\shared\library.dll"?  The closest thing I could find to do this with .Net framework was the GAC, but I'm not really finding any answers for this with Core.  I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: One option is that you can create NuGet packages for the libraries that you want to share between different applications. You can have your own on premises NuGet feed, that is not difficult to setup as explained by Scott Hanselman [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToHostYourOwnNuGetServerAndPackageFeed.aspx)

Comment: I would also like to point you towards two other links by Scott Hanselman. One shows how to update the NuGet references on build server [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuKeeperForAutomatedNuGetPackageReferenceUpdatesOnBuildServers.aspx) and the other shows how to to access the NuGet packages while you are offline [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAccessNuGetWhenNuGetorgIsDownOrYoureOnAPlane.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

> sometimes things change, and we can simply go update the global libraries, and every application that depends on them will adapt to the new code without needing a recompile

Note that this is *exactly* one of the reasons why GAC deployment is usually avoided. If you update a dependency, and that happens to contain a breaking change (in *any* possibly case), then applications will start to break randomly without you having control over that.

Usually, if you update a dependency, you should have to *retest* every application that depends on that before you deploy the updated application. That is why dependency updates (e.g. via NuGet) are deliberate choices you need to make.

.NET Core avoids this in general by never sharing assemblies between applications and by allowing different versions side-by-side. That way, you can update applications one by one without affecting others.

This is actually a primary reason why .NET Core was made in the first place: The .NET Framework is shipped with Windows, and is a global thing. All applications will always use the same framework version. So whenever Microsoft ships an update to the .NET Framework, they have to be **incredibly** careful not to break applications. And that is incredibly difficult because countless applications depend on all kinds of things in the framework. Even fixing a possibly obvious bug can break stuff.

With .NET Core and side-by-side dependencies, this is no longer a problem because updates will not automatically break applications that still depend on older versions. It is a developer’s explicit choice to update an application, shipping newer dependencies.

So you should actually embrace this and start to develop your applications independently. If you have common dependencies, consider creating (private) NuGet packages for those, so that applications can depend on them and so that you have a good way to update them properly.